# Web Service access to Sql Server Architecture

Tags: wcf, azure, ado.net, azure-sql-database, wcf-data-services

I am just getting started with Azure SQL Database and I will be having a Azure SQL server just to retrieve the data but not to update the data. Is storing the data in SQL server the right way of doing it?

If yes, SQL server allows only specific IP addresses to access it. When a user with a different IP address tries to access the data using my ASP.Net site, how will he be able to connect?

Help me with the total architecture of retrieving the data from Azure SQL Database onto asp.net using Ado.Net

Answer (score 1):

basically you have a client (user using a browser/app), middle tier (your .NET application/web-service) and data tier (SQL Azure database).

The middle tier is the only thing that talks with SQL Azure, that runs on a web server in your Azure estate so that is the only thing that needs to be given access to your SQL Azure database.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Middle Tier(web Service) means Web API?